# Put All Images in Asset Catalog?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, resources, asset-catalog

I started a new project in Xcode 5.

1. What is this `Images.xcassets` shenanigans?

   Am I supposed to put the various images I'm using for my app (like button images & stuff) in there or only the `AppIcon` & `LaunchImage`?

   I see I can create a new folder in `Images.xcassets`. Should I create a folder called "Button Icons" or whatever and just throw them in there?

   See, but I just want to add some retina images to my target.

   I'm only supporting iOS 7. So, I don't need to worry about other formats like non-retina.

   Why did they make this so complicated and not document it at all? Why do I need these extra `Contents.json` files?

   It looks like I can uncheck (remove) `Images.xcassets` from the target but not the individual image files within the asset catalog.

   Can I just do things the old way or would I be missing out on compression/performance enhancements?
2. Is there a setting I can set so that my app treats all image files as retina images even if they dont have the `@2x` suffix in their filename?

Comment: upvote for using the word "shenanigans". Make a note of it, I should use it more often in conversation

Answer (score 11):

1. In the "What's New in Xcode 5" WWDC 2013 Session Video, the speaker says `Image.xcassets` "collects all of your image-based resources, such as your launch images, icons, *loose images that you use in your project*, together into one place."

   "Also, Xcode knows about new iOS 7 APIs and so can even optimize the loading of your image-based resources." I'm assuming "it does it for you automatically" as long as you put your images in `Image.xcassets` (or another asset catalog included in your target).

   So, I suggest you suck it up, and adapt or die.
2. I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

There are not retina devices that are still supported by iOS 7 such as iPad mini and iPhone 3GS. Keep that in mind. The images will scale down and still work but I wanted to make sure you knew iOS 7 supported not retina devices.

When you ask for an image by name iOS will look for the image by name. For example, "background.png" if there is a retina image "background@2x.png" and the device is retina iOS will handle that for you. If you only plan on providing retina images there is nothing wrong with making the images all retina and excluding the "@2x" info in the image. name.